# How to overlap timeline animations with anime.js

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Using [Anime.js](https://animejs.com/documentation/), I have a looped timeline animation with staggered delays. I'd like each cycle (i.e. each `.add()`) to begin just before the previous cycle ends. I know this is usually accomplished with offsets but my cycles affect the same elements so adding a negative offset appears to prevent the previous cycle from finishing. Is there a way to loop timeline animations affecting elements with the same class such that animation cycles overlap?

In the snippet below, I am flashing the text, "NOW" to demonstrate when I want the forthcoming animation cycle to begin.

```js
let tl = anime.timeline({
  duration: 500,
  loop: true
})

tl
// cycle 1
.add({
  targets: '.item',
  delay: anime.stagger(100),
  easing: 'linear',
  keyframes: [
    { backgroundColor: '#F0E68C', translateY: -20 },
    { backgroundColor: '#666', translateY: 0 }
  ]
})
// just for demo purposes
.add({
  targets: '.now',
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 250,
  keyframes: [
    { backgroundColor: '#98FB98' },
    { backgroundColor: '#222' }
  ]
}, '-=500')
// cycle 2
.add({
  targets: '.item',
  delay: anime.stagger(100),
  easing: 'linear',
  keyframes: [
    { backgroundColor: '#87CEFA', translateY: -20 },
    { backgroundColor: '#666', translateY: 0 }
  ]
})
// just for demo purposes
.add({
  targets: '.now',
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 250,
  keyframes: [
    { backgroundColor: '#98FB98' },
    { backgroundColor: '#222' }
  ]
}, '-=500');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #222;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 500px;
  background: #666;
}

.now {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-family: monaco;
  color: #222;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.1.0/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<main class="wrapper">
  <p class='now'>now</p>
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Comment: No, I never did. I don't think it's possible with anime.js